# Why does this Python code take 2 minutes to exit when it cannot connect to OBS software?

Tags: python, websocket, python-asyncio

I am new to Python and i don't know much about asyncio.  I want to run this script and if the OBS software it is trying to connect to on 10.11.0.124 is not running to exit the code.  The code does this, but it take 2 minutes before it exits.  I cannot figure out why it does not exit immediately when it cannot connect to the OBS software that is not running on 10.11.0.124.

```
#! /usr/bin/python3

import asyncio
import urllib.request
import sys 
import datetime

from obswsrc import OBSWS
from obswsrc.requests import StartStopStreamingRequest

def logger(logmessage):
    f = open("log.txt", "a")
    f.write(str(datetime.datetime.now()) + " " + logmessage + "\n")
    f.close

async def main():

   try:
        async with OBSWS('10.11.0.124', 4444, "password") as obsws:

            logger("Connection established.")

            while True:

                event = await obsws.event()

                logger(str(format(event.type_name)))

                if(format(event.type_name) == "StreamStarting"):
                    HitURLToLoadAsset = urllib.request.urlopen("http://10.11.0.159/api/v1/assets/control/asset&b0983c0918b94856900040d9a9e8bdbf").read()
                    logger(str(HitURLToLoadAsset))

                if(format(event.type_name) == "StreamStopped"):
                    HitURLToLoadAsset = urllib.request.urlopen("http://10.11.0.159/api/v1/assets/control/asset&3b2fb67002364b269d0c2674a628533c").read()
                    logger(str(HitURLToLoadAsset))

            logger("Connection terminated.")

    except OSError:
        logger("OBS IS NOT RUNNING")

    except:
        logger(str(sys.exc_info()[1]))


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())
loop.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help user4815162342 and wizzwizz4!  Here is my final solution.

I ended up going with wizzwizz4's suggestion of breaking down the connection string so i could use asyncio.wait_for on it.

If anyone cares the code itself is to watch OBS and when streaming is started go change the asset on [Screenly OSE](https://www.screenly.io/ose/) to display the RTMP stream.  When the streaming is stopped switch back to a different asset on Screenly OSE.

```
#! /usr/bin/python3

import asyncio
import urllib.request
import sys
import datetime

from obswsrc import OBSWS
from obswsrc.requests import StartStopStreamingRequest

def logger(logmessage):
    f = open("log.txt", "a")
    f.write(str(datetime.datetime.now()) + " " + logmessage + "\n")
    f.close


async def main():

    try:
        obsws = OBSWS('10.11.0.124', 4444, "password")
        # if no response from OBS in 30 seconds EXIT
        await asyncio.wait_for(obsws.connect(), timeout=30)

        logger("Connection established.")

        while True:

            event = await obsws.event()

            logger(str(format(event.type_name)))

            if(format(event.type_name) == "StreamStarting"):
                HitURLToLoadAsset = urllib.request.urlopen("http://10.11.0.159/api/v1/assets/control/asset&b0983c0918b94856900040d9a9e8bdbf").read()
                logger(str(HitURLToLoadAsset))

            if(format(event.type_name) == "StreamStopped"):
                HitURLToLoadAsset = urllib.request.urlopen("http://10.11.0.159/api/v1/assets/control/asset&3b2fb67002364b269d0c2674a628533c").read()
                logger(str(HitURLToLoadAsset))

    except asyncio.TimeoutError:
        logger("OBS NOT RUNNING-- TIMEOUT!")

    except OSError:
        logger("OBS IS NOT RUNNING")

    except:
        logger(str(sys.exc_info()[1]))

    finally:
        await obsws.close()
        logger("Connection terminated.")



loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()  
loop.run_until_complete(main())
loop.close()
```

Comment: You don't need `obsws.close()` in the `except` clauses if you have it in `finally`. `finally` will execute regardless of whether an exception occurs.

Comment: @user4815162342 Thanks!  I need to start reading more on python.  It is kind of a different language than i am use to.

Comment: Reading is always a good idea, but `finally` in Python works the same as in other languages, such as Java. :)

Answer (score 2):

The `OBSWS` function has a timeout of two minutes, because it uses the `websockets` module internally and that has a default timeout of two minutes.

Detailed breakdown:

- `async with OBSWS(...):` calls [`OBSWS.__init__`](https://github.com/KirillMysnik/obs-ws-rc/blob/master/obswsrc/client.py#L72) and then `await`s [`OBSWS.__aenter__`](https://github.com/KirillMysnik/obs-ws-rc/blob/master/obswsrc/client.py#L216).
- `OBSWS.__init__` does nothing interesting, but [`OBSWS.__aenter__` `await`s](https://github.com/KirillMysnik/obs-ws-rc/blob/master/obswsrc/client.py#L226) [`OBSWS.connect`](https://github.com/KirillMysnik/obs-ws-rc/blob/master/obswsrc/client.py#L145)
- `OBSWS.connect` [`await`s](https://github.com/KirillMysnik/obs-ws-rc/blob/master/obswsrc/client.py#L163-L166) [`websocket.connect`](https://github.com/aaugustin/websockets/blob/master/src/websockets/client.py#L353).
- `websockets.connect` has several different timeouts defined via keyword arguments. It also waits for multiple things. These are:

  - [`self._creating_connection`](https://github.com/aaugustin/websockets/blob/master/src/websockets/client.py#L444), [defined here](https://github.com/aaugustin/websockets/blob/master/src/websockets/client.py#L440)

    - This uses [`loop.create_connection`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.create_connection) which has a **60 second timeout** by default.
    - It then calls [`factory`](https://github.com/aaugustin/websockets/blob/master/src/websockets/client.py#L411-L428) which calls `create_protocol` which [defaults to `klass`](https://github.com/aaugustin/websockets/blob/master/src/websockets/client.py#L386-L387) which [defaults to](https://github.com/aaugustin/websockets/blob/master/src/websockets/client.py#L367) [`WebSocketClientProtocol`](https://github.com/aaugustin/websockets/blob/master/src/websockets/client.py#L33), which subclasses [`WebSocketCommonProtocol`](https://github.com/aaugustin/websockets/blob/master/src/websockets/protocol.py#L59) which probably isn't adding any further delays.
  - [`protocol.handshake(...)`](https://github.com/aaugustin/websockets/blob/master/src/websockets/client.py#L447-L453)
  - [`protocol.fail_connection()`](https://github.com/aaugustin/websockets/blob/master/src/websockets/client.py#L455) in the case of any exception being raised, which does occur.

I don't understand `asyncio` so I just stopped here; there's probably another 60 second delay somewhere but if not... perhaps the computer was just slow.

Comment: Is there any way to reduce this timeout?

Comment: @ChadGray Judging by the source code, it doesn't look like it is... unless you can change it from the `websockets` module. If you figure it out, please add an answer to your question explaining how!

Comment: @ChadGray You can use `asyncio.wait_for` to enforce a timeout for *any* asyncio task.

Comment: @user4815162342 You could add that as an answer; it solves the problem.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 I am having a hard time figuring out where to use the asyncio.wait_for.  I would assume it would be on this line of code, but how would i apply this wait_for 'async with OBSWS('10.11.0.124', 4444, "password") as obsws:'

Comment: @user4815162342 if you have any code examples i can apply to my code above i would appreciate it.  I dont quite understand where i would apply this wait_for.  Thank!

Comment: @ChadGray I don't know if you can do it using the `with` syntax, but if you replace it with [this version](https://github.com/KirillMysnik/obs-ws-rc/blob/master/obswsrc/client.py#L40-L53), wrapping the `await obsws.connect()` line in an `asyncio.wait_for` and catching the timeout error (defined in `asyncio`, can't remember what it's called) it would work.

Comment: @ChadGray Move the whole `async with OBWS(...): ...` into a separate `async def xxx(): ...` and invoke it from `main()` as `await asyncio.wait_for(xxx(), 1)`. This will give `xxx()` 1 second to run, otherwise it will be cancelled and you'll get an `asyncio.TimeoutError` (which you can catch). See [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.wait_for) for an example.

Comment: Thanks!   I see where you are both going with your suggestions.  I will re-write my code and post my final code when i get it working.  Thanks!  Chad

Comment: @ChadGray Post it as an answer; don't edit it into your question please.